# NSXMLParsing returns (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

i'm trying to parse an online xml document, but it seems to return (null) everytime i run the script. What am i doing wrong with my Parsing method?

```
@implementation ViewController
NSString *livescore;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.scorespro.com/rss2/live-soccer.xml"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];



    NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"]) {

        livescore = attributeDict[@"title"];

        NSLog(@"%@", livescore);




    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show us what the logging is? You should also log the “elementName” and the “attributeDict” to debug this.

Comment: Have you verified that `data` isn't `nil`?